# Weak continuity implies continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

This problem is from $\textit{Conway's A course in Functional analysis 2ed, pge 198, problem 4}$. The problem is:
If $\mathscr{G}$ is an open subset $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathscr{B}$ is a Banach space and $$f:\mathscr{G}\rightarrow \mathscr{B}$$ is a map such that for each $\mathscr{x^*}\in \mathscr{B^*}$ the fucntion $\mathscr{x^*\circ} \ \textit{f}$ is continuous. Show that  $\textit{f}$  is also continuous.

Comment: I could not catch the idea of the solution. In Conway's book, the problem has another part involving analyticity of $\textit{f}$. I managed to write a solution, but this part is leaving me hopeless. I can't apply the general idea of continuity  that is: if for a sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $\mathbb{C}$ if $\textit{f}(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $\textit{f}$, I can't show that $\mathscr{x^*}\textit{f}(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $\mathscr{x^*}\textit{f}(x)$.

Comment: Found a solution, actually a counter-example. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748754/if-composition-with-a-linear-functional-is-continuous-is-the-function-continuou?rq=1